# why are xpaths slower

Tags: javascript, dom

Could someone please explain while searching an element in DOM why are Xpaths considered to be slower than CSS selectors.And also are there different engines for different selectors (eg Xpaths , CSS selectors etc. )

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Xpaths aren't considered to be slower, they are slower.  Basic performance testing proves this out (see http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/05/why-css-locators-are-the-way-to-go-vs-xpath/). XPath is more expressive than CSS which means it has more work to do.  It also looks like Xpath hasn't been as optimized, especially on Internet Explorer, and probably never will be since most people don't use Xpath anymore.

As for different engines, every browser uses a different engine for each type.  Within a single browser, there are not multiple implementations for each type.

Comment: Hey Bill, thanks.I wanted to further know why does Xpath take more time to search..I mean the logic..thanks in advance